# Why does ipset succeed on adding ipv4 ranges, but fail on adding ipv6 range?

Tags: iptables, ipv6, ipset

Using *ipset* to clean up bulky *iptable* rulesets does not seem so different between *IPv4* and *IPv6*:

```
# ipset create TEST hash:net family inet
# ipset create DEMO hash:net family inet6
# iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set TEST src -j DROP
# ip6tables -A INPUT -m set --match-set DEMO src -j DROP
```

However, upon adding ip ranges, unexpected **errors occur only for IPv6 ranges**:

```
# ipset add TEST 192.0.2.0-192.0.2.127
# ipset add DEMO 2001:db8::-2001:db8::ffff
ipset v6.34: Syntax error: IP address or IP/cidr must be specified: 2001:db8::-2001:db8::ffff
```

This is unexpected, as *ipset* appears to be able to parse these *IPv6* addresses:

```
# ipset add DEMO 2001:db8::/112
# ipset del DEMO 2001:db8::/112
# ipset add DEMO 2001:db8::ffff/112
# ipset -L DEMO | tail -2
Members:
2001:db8::/112
```

Why would *ipset* accept `fromaddr-toaddr` ranges for IPv4 but consider the same thing a syntax error for *IPv6*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromaddr-toaddr` syntax is only supported for IPv4. Use `cidr` notation to add *IPv6* ranges.

> For the **inet** family one can add or delete multiple entries by
>   specifying a range or a network of IPv4 addresses in the IP address
>   part of the entry - [man 8 ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html)